# Lubuntu Dual-Boot on a MacBook?

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, macbook, apple

Is it possible to Dual-Boot Lubuntu on a MacBook?
If so how would I do it?
I have not tried as yet as I wanted to know the proper way to do such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible!

You should start by modifying the size of the partition where mac is installed with the mac "Disk Utility".
Then you should install rEFIt: http://refit.sourceforge.net/ which simplify the booting of linux distros.
At last you insert the Lubuntu cd and install normally

EDIT: you may also use rEFInd: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ instead of rEFIt as the rEFIt website states, but I personally never tried it.